# Lambda coming from jar file need their interfaces on the classpath to be compiled, unknown interfaces are java.util.function.Predicate

Tags: android-jack-and-jill

I have an external jar library . i can import this file in intellij idea without any problem with java 8 . but when i add this file to android studio , i got this Error

> Error:ApiClass.java:114-115: Lambda coming from jar file need their interfaces on the classpath to be compiled, unknown interfaces are java.util.function.Predicate

any one can help me ?

build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "insta.ir.instagramfollowercustomer"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled = true

    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/InstaNewLibraryProject.jar')
}
```

and gradle propertis :

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```